# More Readable Way to Write Complex If Statement

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

I am writing a User Defined Type Guard for my Angular project.

The following `if` statements (marked by my comments) work perfectly well — but i can't help but think there would be a more readable way to write them.

The following first checks that the `Object` passed to the function has the required props (and exits early if not).

The next (and third) `if` statement checks the value of the prop `activity` is a String.

The second and fourth `if` statements need to check that the values of props `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are either of the type String, or that they are Objects and that they have their own props `.sv` who's values is the String `timestamp`.

```
import { GridMetadata } from './grid-metadata';

export function isGridMetadata(obj: any): obj is GridMetadata {
  [ 'activity', 'createdAt', 'totalReps', 'updatedAt' ].every((prop) => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) return false;
  });

  if (typeof obj.activity !== 'string') return false;

  // TODO: Better way to write this?
  if (typeof obj.createdAt === 'string') {}
  else if (obj.createdAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && obj.createdAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp') {}
  else return false;

  if (typeof obj.totalReps !== 'number') return false;

  // TODO: Better way to write this?
  if (typeof obj.updatedAt === 'string') {}
  else if (obj.updatedAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && obj.updatedAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp') {}
  else return false;

  return true;
}
```

There may indeed be a better an more readable way to write the entire function?!

Comment: First you need to seperate your logic cases, then you might want to use ternary for binary cases (only one if with else), and use switch case for multiple cases (more than one if), this way your code will be very readable. Just wondering why are you using empty statements ?

Comment: I think you have a problem with the `every` statement. The `return false` does not return your `isGridMetadata` function, it just returns the anonymous function that is passed to `every`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the every value is not stored anywhere. And you can directly return the check:

```
var objHasPropertiesInTheList = [ 'activity', 'createdAt', 'totalReps', 'updatedAt' ].every((prop) => {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
  });
```

Now `objHasPropertiesInTheList` will be false if in the object there are not all these properties of the list. So add the check here and do what you need if there are not all the properties.

Then this:

```
if (typeof obj.createdAt === 'string') {}
  else if (obj.createdAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && obj.createdAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp') {}
  else return false;
```

Can be simply:

```
if (typeof(obj.createdAt) !== 'string' && obj.createdAt['.sv'] !== 'timestamp') {
  return false;
}
```

And same for the last one:

```
if (typeof(obj.updatedAt ) !== 'string' && obj.updatedAt['.sv'] !== 'timestamp') {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't make mistakes :

```
if (typeof obj.activity !== 'string' ||
    (!typeof obj.createdAt === 'string' && !(obj.createdAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && obj.createdAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp') || 
    typeof obj.totalReps !== 'number' ||
    (!typeof obj.updatedAt === 'string' && !(obj.updatedAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && obj.updatedAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp')) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Apologies if I am incorrect, but I can't see how this would work. I would need to be inside a loop to check `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` otherwise `prop` is undefined. If I was in a loop, the statement would surely return `false` as even if the criteria for that `prop` was met, the other three properties would not exist and therefore fail?

Comment: Done, now it should be okay

Answer (score 0):

I think an equivalent and more compact way to rewrite it is:

```js
function validateDateProperty(obj, dateProp) {
    const dateVal = obj[dateProp];
    return typeof dateVal === 'string' || (dateVal.hasOwnProperty('.sv') && dateVal['.sv'] === 'timestamp');
}

export function isGridMetadata(obj : any) : obj is GridMetadata {
    if !(['activity', 'createdAt', 'totalReps', 'updatedAt'].every(prop => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))) {
        return false;
    }
    return (
        typeof obj.activity === 'string'
        && typeof obj.totalReps === 'number'
        && validateDateProperty(obj, 'createdAt')
        && validateDateProperty(obj, 'updatedAt')        
    );
}
```